# "Betazoids" in The Last Starfighter versus Star Trek: The Next Generation

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, terminology, betazoid, the-last-starfighter

Released in 1984, [***The Last Starfighter***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087597/) is sometimes accused of borrowing too many themes and plot points from contemporaneous sci-fi fare, including the *Star Wars* trilogy.

But conversely, one element of *The Last Starfighter* reappears only a few years later in *Star Trek: The Next Generation*: the term **Betazoid**.

- In *The Last Starfighter*, the term refers to a type of robot / android / replicant.

[image]

- In *TNG*, the term refers to a race of telepathic / empathic humanoids from the planet Betazed.

[image]

**Given that *TNG* hit the air only three years after *Starfighter* was released, is there a connection here, or is the appearance of the term in *TNG* a mere coincidence?**

Comment: @Richard : Interesting --- I haven't watched the film lately, and I can't remember exactly how the unit is referred to in the film (also can't find a script).  However, at least three or four sites (containing synopses of the film, etc.) refer to the unit as a "Betazoid".

Comment: @Richard : For instance:  http://geekleagueofamerica.com/2014/06/13/1984-the-greatest-year-ii-the-last-starfighter/, http://www.megadroid.com/movie_tv_robots.htm, http://www.g4tv.com/articles/370/the-robot-all-star-team/

Comment: @Richard : Also, here: http://byrcesmovies.tumblr.com/post/10977604552/favourites

Comment: Am I the only one who saw this question's title and got super-excited about the prospect of something called "Betazoids: The Last Starfighter"?

Comment: For the record, there are [some connections](http://www.imdb.com/search/name?roles=tt0087597,tt0092455) between the film and the show (they shared several actors and film crew) but no major links between the writing staff or direction

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest answer is that there's no obvious linguistic connection. In the film, there's no mention of the [Beta Unit](http://thelaststarfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Beta) being a "Betazoid". The most likely explanation is that the people you've referenced in your comments are mis-remembering the line from the film where he's referred to as a "***simuloid***"

> **Beta:** *Course I do. I'm the beta unit.*
>
> **Alex:** *What the hell's a beta unit?*
>
> **Beta:** *A beta unit is a simuloid...*

Interestingly, in the official [Alan Dean Foster novelisation](http://thelaststarfighter.wikia.com/wiki/The_Last_Starfighter_%28novel%29), he's referred to throughout as a ***simulacrum***, not a simuloid...

> "I told you," the Beta snapped as he tried to get a fix on the
>   assassin's position. It had to be moving now, wondering why its first
>   shot hadn't turned its target into a motionless mass of smoldering
>   flesh. Confusion would buy the Beta some time. "I'm not Alex. I'm a
>   duplicate of him, a simulacrum, a Beta unit."

Comment: I think your explanation for the mutation is probably spot on -- thanks.

Comment: Even then, coincidence is not beyond the realms of possibility - both "Beta-" and "-zoid" are common Sci-Fi kind of words (or bits of words)